# Find next items to tag in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to parse a HTML file with Beautiful Soup and Python like

```
<h1>Title 1</h1>
<div class="item"><p>content 1</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>content 2</p></div>
...
<h1>Title 2</h1>
<div class="item"><p>content 3</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>content 4</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>content 5</p></div>
...
```

How can I parse this into a dictionary like

```
{
   "Title 1": [
      {
         "content": "content 1"
      },
      {
         "content": "content 2"
      }
   ],
   "Title 2": [
      {
         "content": "content 3"
      },
      {
         "content": "content 4"
      },
      {
         "content": "content 5"
      }
   ]
}
```

I've tried it with nextSibling, but I am not able check the tag name.

Comment: You can't parse it to dictionary with the same keys , you must use list or something else (i say about `content` key)

Comment: I've edited the dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve this:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
data = {}
row = []
title = ""
for tag in soup:
    print(tag)
    if tag.name == 'h1':
        if title:
            data[title] = row
        row = []
        title = tag.string

    elif tag.name == 'div':
        row.append(tag.string)

if title:
    data[title] = row
```

The idea is to iterate over the tags.
If the current tag is a `<h1>`, then create a new content list.
Else, if it is a `<div>` tag, then append its content to the current content list.
When a new `<h1>` tag is found, put the current content list into the global data structure (that is a dictionary), under the name of the last title.

The type of a tag can be found in `tag.name`.
This is what you need to check so as to find if a tag is a `<h1>` or a `<div>`.

This gives a little bit different structure than what you asked for, but I think it is a better data structure, for the keys in your dictionary are always `content`, so basically no key is needed, and a list is better.

---

Test input:

```
html = """<h1>Title 1</h1>
<div class="item"><p>content 1</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>content 2</p></div>
<h1>Title 2</h1>
<div class="item"><p>content 3</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>content 4</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>content 5</p></div>
"""
```

Output:

```
{'Title 1': ['content 1', 'content 2'], 'Title 2': ['content 3', 'content 4', 'content 5']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `next_sibling` and check tag type by `.name`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
temp_tag = soup.h1
result = {temp_tag.text: []}
temp_key = temp_tag.text
while True:
    temp_tag = temp_tag.next_sibling
    if temp_tag.name == 'div':
        buf = temp_tag.contents[0].text
        result[temp_key].append({'content': buf})
    elif temp_tag.name == 'h1':
        temp_key = temp_tag.text
        result[temp_key] = []
    else:
        break

print(result)
```

The output of this code:

```
{
u'Title 1': [
    {'content': u'content 1'},
    {'content': u'content 2'}
    ], 
u'Title 2': [
    {'content': u'content 3'},
    {'content': u'content 4'},
    {'content': u'content 5'}
    ]
}
```